# Foreach Issue: collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, data-binding

I am having an issue with this code. Basically the `ProfileControl` is a custom control, `profileList` is `ListBox` and `profileCollection` is an `ObservableCollection`.

```
foreach (ProfileControl item in profileList.SelectedItems) 
{
     profileCollection.Remove(item);
}
```

The code is working perfectly but I am getting the message:

> Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute.

Please advise me, Thanks.

Comment: Please follow the exception. I'm sure that `ReferenceEquals(profileList.SelectedItems, profileCollection) == true` so you can't iterate with foreach and remove element from a list that you are iterating on.

Comment: use foreach till item.count ,its the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `profileList` is bound to `profileCollection`. So when you call `profileCollection.Remove` databinding engine  will update the `profileList.SelectedItems` collection to keep in sync.

foreach can't reliably work with collection which is being modified while iterated. You could make a copy of `profileList.SelectedItems` and iterate over it.

```
var selectedItems = profileList.SelectedItems
                               .Cast<ProfileControl>()
                               .ToList();
foreach (ProfileControl item in selectedItems) 
{
     profileCollection.Remove(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to convert it to a List:

```
foreach (ProfileControl item in profileList.SelectedItems.ToList())
```

Indeed, you are deleting an item from a list that you are currently browsing...